# Issues when changing permalink Structure

Tags: permalinks

I wanted to change the slug of the portfolio of my page, it is actually /portfolio-item/ i went to  my `custom_post_types.php` file and changed the rewrite rule of the slug to my needs, but when i flush my permalink structure all my portfolio items get their permalink changed to `mysite.es/myslug//`. Am i doing something wrong? Is anything else needed when changing the permalink structure?

```
// Register Custom Post Type: 'Portfolio'
function ss_framework_register_post_type_portfolio() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Portfolio', 'ss_framework' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Project', 'ss_framework' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'ss_framework' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project', 'ss_framework' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project', 'ss_framework' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Project', 'ss_framework' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Project', 'ss_framework' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Projects', 'ss_framework' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found', 'ss_framework' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in Trash', 'ss_framework' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Project:', 'ss_framework' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'Portfolio', 'ss_framework' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'portfolio-categories' ),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-item' ),
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => SS_BASE_URL . 'functions/assets/img/icon-portfolio.png'
    );

    register_post_type( 'portfolio', apply_filters( 'ss_framework_register_post_type_portfolio', $args ) );

}add_action('init', 'ss_framework_register_post_type_portfolio');
```

Comment: try pasting your custom_post_type.php code here to get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the error, it was the theme itself who blocked the portfolio form changing, edited some code from the theme solved it. The website is done in an old theme which is no longer supported :(